# GCC error during compile-time evaluation of nested accesses via pointer to member

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, constexpr

This is accepted by Clang but not GCC:

```
struct inner {int x;};
constexpr struct outer {inner i;} o{};

// definition of x4 results in GCC error:
// "accessing value of 'o' through a 'const int' glvalue in a constant expression"
constexpr int x1 {             &(o.i)->*(&inner::x)}; // ok
constexpr int x2 { (&o->*(&outer::i)).x            }; // ok
          int x3 {&(&o->*(&outer::i))->*(&inner::x)}; // ok
constexpr int x4 {&(&o->*(&outer::i))->*(&inner::x)}; // error
```

GCC 9.4 error message is

```
error: accessing value of 'o' through a 'const int' glvalue in a constant expression
```

Is this type of access allowed inside constexpr?

The behavior appears to be the same on all version of GCC that support C++11.

Answer (score 0):

Since the code is accepted by Clang and MSVC, apparently it was just a GCC bug that manifested itself till GCC 9, and was fixed in GCC 10 that accepts your code as well. Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3EdhaK9of